# Maximum runs scored in an inning by a batsman

Tags: cricket, trivia

What are the maximum runs scored in an inning of 50 overs by 1 batsman?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! This question needs more details - what level of cricket: domestic, international, club? Also, assuming you're talking about international cricket, it's very easy to find the answer by a quick Google search: [highest individual ODI score](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=highest+odi+score+individual&oq=highest+odi+score+individual&aqs=chrome..69i57.912j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=highest+individual+odi+score) should give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 27th November 2014, for [One-Day internationals](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;template=results;type=batting;view=innings), it's Rohit Sharma who scored 264 v Sri Lanka in Kolkata on the 13th November 2014.

For other forms of 50-over cricket, you'd need to consult the national sites, available from that link also.